# Получение размера кеша других приложений

Tags: android, кэширование

Через следующий код я пытаюсь получить пакеты всех приложений чтобы затем подставляя их пути получить размер его кеша. Но всегда выходит 0. Ребят, я как то не так к вопросу подхожу или это невозможно?

Есть мысль что нужны какие то спец разрешения?

Добавлены также в манифесте.

Нужно именно получать размер кеша, а не удалять сразу все кеши.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> applicationInfos = pm.getInstalledApplications(GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo ai : applicationInfos
        ) {
             File file = new File(ai.dataDir + File.separator + "cache");
            Log.d(TAG, "Package: " + ai.dataDir + " Size:  " + new File(ai.dataDir).length() +
                            "  CachePath:  " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " CacheSize:  " + file.getPath().length());

        }
```

Comment: Приложения не имеют прав на доступ к содержимому папок других приложений. Это возможно только через рут.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо! Подскажи пожалуйста еще эта информация есть в доках гугла? О том что мол доступа нет и нужен рут, может там даже будет ссылка на то как рут запросить

Comment: О том, что файлы доступны только приложению-владельцу здесь: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal Рут на Андроиде "вне закона" - поэтому в доках гугла об этом точно не написано. И чтобы эта функция была доступна, сам юзер должен найти рецепт для своей модели аппарата и "взломать" его. То есть нельзя считать, что ваш код, требующий рут, будет работать хотя бы на половине трубок.

Comment: @woesss интересно как другие Cleaner программы работают в таком случае :\
как то к служебной программе по очистке обращаются что-ли.. даже не знаю куда копать

Comment: Гуглить не пробовали? Всё сводится к 2 вариантам: 1) через рут доступ (тут уже понятно, что не для всех?); 2) через рефлексию вызывают скрытый метод, которым просят освободить заведомо бОльшый объём памяти, чем доступно и занято кэшем - это побуждает систему грохнуть кэш, так как это временные файлы и могут быть удалены без зазрения совести в любой момент + ручная очистка кэша на "внешних" накопителях, к ним доступ пока ещё возможен через запрос `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`-привелегии: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45732697.

Comment: Но второй вариант доказывает бессмысленность процедуры - система сама удалит старый кэш, как только кому-то понадобится место на диске. А если подумать, то это ещё и вредно, так как после очистки приложения будут заново заполнять свой кэш - это снизит скорость их запуска и следовательно производительность, отзывчивость всей системы в этот момент. А так же лишние  записи-перезаписи ускоряют смерть накопителя. Вообще большинство "оптимизаторов" системы не менее вредны, чем полезны.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо  за объяснение и потраченное время